# XMPP Library issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I'm trying to use XMPPFramework.
In my Pod file I have

```
pod 'XMPPFramework'
```

After installing, I'm trying to build project, but it doesn't builds.
I have an error.[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

**UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: from [Github](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) description: " The version pushed to CocoaPods is very out of date, use master branch for now
`pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'
# pod 'XMPPFramework'"`

Comment: In this case I have another issue. Look at my update.